# Ubuntu Ver. 20.04, cannot start fullscreen on mode single application Desktop Entry

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, startup-applications, fullscreen

I want to run an application with mode single application on startup Linux Ubuntu 20.04 without desktop, but the application can't open fullscreen, how to solve this problem?

Added in `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` file: `Exec=/usr/bin/firefox --fullscreen` or `Exec=/usr/bin/firefox --start-maximized`, but not work.

[image]